# Tensorflow kernel dies and restarts automatically in jupyter with python 2.7

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Kernal dies automatically in jupyter for the following code and also in background python 2.7 unexpectedelly closes. What is the solution? Is this problem with python or jupyter itself? Somewhere I found that batch size may cause the problem but I even reduced batch size from 256 to 32. So far no difference.

```
def train(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, batch_size, iterations=1000, learning_rate=0.5):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 100]))
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
   #a1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 100])
    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 11]))
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([11]))
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 11])

    z1 = tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1
    a1 = tf.nn.relu(z1)
    y = tf.matmul(a1, w2) + b2

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    #train
    parameters = {}
    i = 0
    j = batch_size
    for k in range(iterations):
        batch_x = X_train[i:j,:]
        batch_y = y_train[i:j,:]
        print batch_x.shape
        print batch_y.shape
        i += batch_size 
        j += batch_size 
        if(i > X_train.shape[0] or j > y_train.shape[0]):
             i += batch_size % X_train.shape[0]
             j += batch_size % y_train.shape[0]
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y})
        if( k % 100 == 0):
            print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: X_val, y_: y_val}))

    parameters = {"w1": w1,
               "b1": b1,
               "w2": w2,
               "b2": b2
    }
    return parameters
```

Comment: have you tried run just from terminal or ipython ?

Comment: from ipython.....and when i ran from terminal by placing code in .py file i get following error                                                                      /framework/dtypes.py", line 289, in <module>
    dtype_range = {np.bool_: (False, True),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bool_'

Comment: Even in normal terminal python I am not able to import numpy. May be I need to reinstall numpy

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: I installed tensorflow from starting but still the same problem. Sysytem is not able to find numpy..please help.............